# I am trying to open a webpage on the UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to open a webpage on the UIWebView which is secured. I am getting that error message also. But if i try to open it in safari it is giving an alert and i can continue from there forcefully. How can i implement that using UIWebView

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest choosing a username, reading [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and, you might want to post the code that you're using now, or give a better description.

Comment: what are the errors and alerts?

Comment: can you please provide some more information.

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear with your question but i understood something like you want to load a web page in UIWebView some of the snippet may use for you

```
 UIWebView *loacalWebView=[[uiwebView alloc]initwithFrame:self.view.frame];
loacalWebView.delegate=self;
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.co.in";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[loacalWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```